# What means "p" in select p... statement?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

```
private void addPersonToEvent(Long personId, Long eventId) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();

    Person aPerson = (Person) session
            .createQuery("select p from Person p left join fetch p.events where p.id = :pid")
            .setParameter("pid", personId)
            .uniqueResult(); // Eager fetch the collection so we can use it detached
    Event anEvent = (Event) session.load(Event.class, eventId);

    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

This code from hibernate reference. I don't understand what means p in this "select p" SQL statement. What is the "p"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Hibernate Query Language, or HQL, it should not be read as plain SQL as you're doing.

P is the alias of the entity to return.

Basic explanation of the HQL query (not SQL):

```
select p -- the entity to retrieve
from Person p -- Person entity aliased p
left join fetch p.events -- left join with entity Events, check the entity mapping between Person and Event entities
where p.id = :pid -- p.id is the field id from Person entity, :pid is a named parameter called pid
```

For more info, refer to [Hibernate HQL documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html)

Comment: Thank's. Can you explain all this statement (select p from Person p left join fetch p.events where p.id = :pid) in short?

Answer (score 3):

It is just an alias that you will use to query an specific entity. These aliases are used in JPQL/HQL. This will be treat as the entity and you can use (dot) to refer the fields in the entity.